# The "Public Link" in Developer Profile behaves the same regardless of whether your link is valid or not

Tags: bug

If you enter a Public Link in your developer profile, it activates the links below (with your suffix attached), and the *"Make Public"* button instead becomes a *"Delete"* button.

[image]

However if you enter an *invalid* link, although it returns an error message, the behavior is no different:

[image]

Although the *"Story view"* and *"Traditional view"* links aren't valid, they are still activated and clickable (clicking on them returns a `404 Not Found`).

I'd imagine that the UI/UX updates shouldn't occur if the link is not valid.